# Automatic font change in templates of docusign

Tags: docusignapi

Recently I have changed my template on docusign web console. And after that I observed that all the docusign field's font has been changed to some other font. I have set it as **Times new Roman** earlier, but after latest template change its showing some other font. The weird thing is that font change has been observed in other templates also which I haven't touched. Is there anybody observing same problem? Or is there any change on docusign which caused this problem?

I am using demo.docusign.net account.

Answer (score 0):

Did you export and re-import the templates? The font type is not included in the Template XML.

If this is happening for templates that have not been modified between when the fonts switched, I would contact DocuSign Support to file a possible bug with all of the relevant information.

Comment: I have not import or export the template, I had updated only one document with in the template . After upload i have check the field property in the docusign console,which says the font is "Times New Roman" but in the generated document it is different.